# What does this alias in Elixir do?

Tags: elixir

https://github.com/wojtekmach/acme_bank/blob/master/apps/bank/lib/bank/model.ex#L10

```
alias Bank.{
  Account,
  Customer,
  Deposit,
  Ledger,
  Repo,
  Transfer,
  Entry
}
```

Without it I get a `Ecto.Queryable not implemented for Foo, the given module does not exist`.  How is that pulling in the Ecto query stuff into the models?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the equivalent of doing

```
alias Bank.Account
alias Bank.Customer
alias Bank.Deposit
alias Bank.Ledger
alias Bank.Repo
alias Bank.Transfer
alias Bank.Entry
```

This form just allows you to save some keystrokes when you have multiple modules that start with the same prefix.

As for your error, the code is probably doing something like

```
Repo.all(from a in Account)
```

And since you commented / deleted this alias, `Account` no longer has any meaning.

Answer (score 1):

In Elixir (and actually in any other languages) you should organize your code into a context which groups multiple modules based on their functionalities. In this case, the common context is `Bank`.

As already mentioned, this:

```
alias Bank.{
  Account,
  Customer,
  Deposit,
  Ledger,
  Repo,
  Transfer,
  Entry
}
```

is just a shortcut for this:

```
alias Bank.Account
alias Bank.Customer
alias Bank.Deposit
alias Bank.Ledger
alias Bank.Repo
alias Bank.Transfer
alias Bank.Entry
```

If you remove `alias` your module is no longer aware of these aliases, and when you call `Repo.all(from a in Account)` it's trying to execute this command on `Account` module which doesn't exist (it's supposed to be `Bank.Account`).

Alias is [responsible for giving an alternative name to a given module](https://curiosum.dev/blog/alias-import-require-use-in-elixir).